# Pandasframe row indexes reload

Tags: python, pandas, pandastable

Currently I am developing small app to practise new librarie but I am facing interesting issue. In the moment I search in my Pandasframe and I movetoSelection everything is perfect except my row **header indexes disappear**. I already tried many way but non of them solved it.

Search method:

`````
    def open_input_dialog_event(self):

        if self.loaded_df is None:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Search", "No data loaded. Please load data first.")
            return

        dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter a search query:", title="Search")
        search_query = dialog.get_input().strip()

        if not search_query:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Search", "Please enter a search query.")
            return

        # Check if the search query is in the currently displayed data
        matched_rows = [
            row_index
            for row_index, row in enumerate(self.pt.model.df.itertuples(index=False), start=1)
            if any(search_query.lower() in str(val).lower() for val in row)
        ]

        if not matched_rows:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Search", "No matching records found.")
            return

        # Move to the first matched row (you can customize this behavior)
        self.pt.movetoSelection(row=matched_rows[0]-1)
        # Ensure the widget is updated and displayed
        self.pt.show()
        # Force a redraw/update of the widget
        self.pt.show()

        self.pt.redraw()

````your text`
[Before search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKRd5.png)
[After search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrG6P.png)
[All code](https://pastebin.com/Ar8adUVU)


I tried hiding, showing indexes according to documentation, reloading all widget and reseting indexes. MY expectation was that after I search and find some term row indexes will be visible after moving to row fith found term.
`````